# Swift: How to get UIScrollView ClipsToBounds work only horizontally.

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

On my View I have two `UIScrollView` on the left and right side with `UIStackView` in them, which will hold a few `UIButton`'s.

Each button has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so that user can drag and drop the button to the main view.

But, since the buttons are on a `UIScrollView` when dragging on the main view, they sort of disappear and only appear when the button is dropped.To prevent this, I have done

`scrollView.clipsToBounds = false`

and then the drag and drop started working perfectly. But, It has given me a new issue.  Now, because the `clipsToBounds` is `false` when I scroll, the buttons in stackView goes out of bounds like this

[image: Screen Layout]

Now, my question is how do I limit or lock my scrollview's `clipToBounds` so that it works only vertically and I can lock my bounds horizontally so that when I scroll, it doesn't go out of bounds.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the goal, but why are you not using another view to mask your UIScrollView ? So you set clipsToBounds = false, and mask the top/bottom with an opaque UIView

Comment: @CZ54 I did as you suggested and its working now, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @CZ54 suggested in the comments, I have moved both the scroll views into a separate view and have taken another view in the remaining part. then, I have masked the container views to make sure the scrolling is perfect and does not go out of the bounds.

```
    leftScrollView.clipsToBounds = false
    rightScrollView.clipsToBounds = false        

    homeContainerView.clipsToBounds = false
    awayContainerView.clipsToBounds = false

    let leftMaskLayer = CALayer()
    leftMaskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    leftMaskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.centerView.bounds.width, height: self.centerView.bounds.height-50)
    leftContainerView.layer.mask = leftMaskLayer

    let rightMaskLayer = CALayer()
    rightMaskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    rightMaskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -self.centerView.bounds.width, y: 0, width: self.centerView.bounds.width + 100, height: self.centerView.bounds.height)
    rightContainerView.layer.mask = rightMaskLayer
```